# enum declaration string from db to array

Tags: php, arrays, string, enums, explode

After using a "SHOW COLUMNS" I get a string in the "Type" column which looks like so when printed:
`'enum('0','1','2','3')'`

I need this string to be converted to a simple array like
`[0,1,2,3]`

Is there a faster or generally better way than using str_replace(s) to clean the string to `0,1,2,3` and then using explode on it?

Comment: It's a bad idea to have an `ENUM` whose values are numbers. The whole point of ENUM is to encode strings as numbers.

Comment: I can't think of a better way to parse it other than what you suggested.